# c# Gen 2 memory leak problems

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, profiler

Ok, so there a problem.
I have sever app, that work with 1000 connections.
App checked with Profilers for leaks\etc, there no objects that stay in memory, so **used** memory dont increase with time. But **unused** memory in gen 2 increase nonstop.

I`l try to call GC.Collect manually, but its dont help and dont clean unused gen 2 memory.
There a two screenshots from ANTS profiler. As you can see on this screenshots - i get nonstop increase of Unused memory allocated by net and that this memory from gen2.

Screenshot 1: http://pumpshooter.com/kaoT1zaE

Screenshot 2: http://pumpshooter.com/F9g1EInv

Do you have any ideas why i get this problem and how i can fix it?

Comment: Are you complaining about 200mb of memory? In .Net? In an app with 1000 connections?

Comment: Sounds like fragmentation due to pinning of socket buffers. Pre-allocate one huge buffer.

Comment: Yep, just becouse of byte[ushort.Max] buffer. And on screen - 2000 connections (2000*ushortMax) = ~130MB, problem in unused (green) memory from screen 1, which is gen 2 allocated

Comment: #2 But why its increase with time? buffer for each client create after client connected and die with client disconnected

Comment: With fragmentation usage can easily rise to 2x the actual used bytes because the gaps in memory can be 99% as big as the allocations. Why do you even need 64K of memory of read buffer for socket reads. Try 4K and maybe the issue is solved for you. Or allocate one huge buffer on app start. Or, read 1 byte to wait for data to be available. Then, read a full buffer to read the rest. That way, only tiny amounts are required in a pinned state.